# Averaging the sequence across a diagonal

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, analysis

Let $a_{i,j} \in [0, 1]$, $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$, be such that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\sum_{i \in [-n, n] \cap \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{j \in [-n,n] \cap \mathbb{Z}} a_{i, j} = L \in [0, 1]. \tag{1}
$$

> Is it true that
> $$
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)}\sum_{i \in [-n, n] \cap \mathbb{Z}} a_{i, i} = L \tag{2}
> $$

If we assign the element $a_{i, j}$ to the corresponding point $(i, j)$ in the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$, then
$$
S_n := \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\sum_{i \in [-n, n] \cap \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{j \in [-n,n] \cap \mathbb{Z}} a_{i, j}
$$
can be viewed as the average of the sequence $(a_{i, j})_{i, j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ restricted to the square $[-n, n]^2 \cap \mathbb{Z}^2$. On the other hand
$$
S_n^* := \frac{1}{(2n+1)}\sum_{i \in [-n, n] \cap \mathbb{Z}} a_{i, i}
$$
represents the average of the elements on the diagonal of $[-n, n]^2 \cap \mathbb{Z}^2$.

It seems that $(2)$ should hold, if the elements on the diagonal are in some sense representative. But is it true in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_{i,i}=b$ and $a_{i,j}=c$ if $i\neq j$. Then splitting the sum over the diagonal and its complement,
$$
S_n=\frac{1}{2n+1} b+\frac{(2n+1)^2-(2n+1)}{(2n+1)^2}c,
$$
which converges to $c$, but $S_n^*=b$. Since we are free to choose $b$ and $c$, we can get a counter-example.